# Entity Framework 6 - isTemporal get object with all history as property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have an entity:

```
public class Review
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Text { get; set; } 
    public string Author { get; set; } 
}
```

I set it as temporal table like that and it works great:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Review>()
            .ToTable("Review", c => c.IsTemporal());
```

Now I would like to extend it so that I can create a method to get all Reviews with all history. In order to do that I added (maybe that's wrong) a field:

```
public class Review
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Text { get; set; } 
    public string Author { get; set; } 
    public IList<Review> History { get; set; } 
}
```

but then in context I have no idea how to fill that `History` list, any ideas?

Maybe some joins or group by id?

Just to take all `Reviews` (all versions together with temporal (in the past) I can do:

```
return _dbContext.Reviews.TemporalAll()
```

but this is not exactly what I wanted as I would like to have nested list of changes for each current `Review`.

Comment: Do you have an instance of Review? If yes then just access History field and add a new item

Comment: @BasilKosovan I just want to use functionality provided by IsTemporal. So whenever I update an instance of Review new object automatically is created which is nice, now I just want to have all versions in my History property and I need to know how to write a query to get it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would sugeest to create DTO class for that:

```cs
public class ReviewDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Text { get; set; } 
    public string Author { get; set; } 
    public IList<Review> History { get; set; } 
}
```

Then you can query database in the fooowing way:

```cs
var query = _dbContext.Reviews
    .Select(r => new ReviewDTO
    {
        Id = r.Id,
        Text = r.Text,
        Author = r.Author,
        History = _dbContext.Reviews.TemporalAll()
            .Where(x => x.Id == r.Id)
            .ToList()
    })
```